# Jawr gzip_ -bundle url end up unauthorized with StarkSecurity -plugin

Tags: grails, jawr

We are developing Grails-app that uses Stark Security for auth/authz. I recently added Jawr-plugin and bundled i18n-messages to be used in javascript.

The problem is that jawr generates url for the bundles such as: **/gzip_1188185019.en/bundles/lib.js** which Stark Security rejects because it hasn't been mapped. I feel that it is a wrong solution (and does it even work?) to permit /gzip_** -urls by configuring Stark. In debug mode there is no problem since the url generated by Jawr is: /bundles/lib.js.

How can I configure Jawr not to prefix the urls with f.e.g. /gzip_1188185019.en/? Tested jawr.gzip.on=false but that did not help (just dropped the gzip_ -prefix).

P.S.
We've been trying to get rid of Stark Security but it seems that we're stuck with it for now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**jawr.js.mapping = '/script/'** prepended /script/ to the /gzip_xxxxx I was experiencing. Case closed, thanks to all participants.

Comment: FYI, I would highly recommend using the Grails resources plugin instead of jawr.

Comment: @Don, does resources-plugin enable bunding of i18n-messages?

Comment: The `messages*.properties` are normally used only on the server-side, so in that case there's no reason to include them in a bundle. If you have some mechanism that converts the messages to JSON (for example), you can include that .js file in a bundle

Comment: @Don Actually we use them in javascript in alerts and confirmations. For example translation key js.confirm.some.action can be called in javascript: js.confirm.some.action() /*returns the translation*/; after bundled with Jawr.